# Is thera a GUI tool for setting up the samba server?

Tags: release-loki, samba

system-config-samba used to work in Freya, but it isn't now, here is the error message:

> (system-config-samba:17094): Gtk-WARNING **: 無法在 module_path 中找出佈景主題引擎：‘pixmap’，
>
> (system-config-samba:17094): Gtk-WARNING **: 無法在 module_path 中找出佈景主題引擎：‘pixmap’，
>
> (system-config-samba:17094): Gtk-WARNING **: 無法在 module_path 中找出佈景主題引擎：‘pixmap’，
>
> (system-config-samba:17094): Gtk-WARNING **: 無法在 module_path 中找出佈景主題引擎：‘pixmap’，
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/sbin/system-config-samba", line 45, in
>
> mainWindow.MainWindow(debug_flag)
>
> File "/usr/share/system-config-samba/mainWindow.py", line 121, in **init**
>
> self.basic_preferences_win = basicPreferencesWin.BasicPreferencesWin(self, self.xml, self.samba_data, self.samba_backend, self.main_window)
>
> File "/usr/share/system-config-samba/basicPreferencesWin.py", line 97, in **init**
>
> self.admin = libuser.admin()
>
> SystemError: could not open configuration file `/etc/libuser.conf': No such file or directory.

Comment: Take a look at this [Ubuntu question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/785877/where-is-the-samba-configuration-gui-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: They suggest to use system-config-samba, but it just doesn't work on elementary OS.

Answer (score 1):

- Create file: `sudo touch /etc/libuser.conf`
- Run with sudo: `sudo system-config-samba`
- *** Work for me!

Answer (score 0):

Run this command: `sudo gedit /etc/libuser.conf`

Select all this lines and paste into the file (libuser.conf). See libuser.conf(5) for more information.

Do not modify the default module list if you care about unattended calls to programs (i.e., scripts) working!

```
[import]
# Data from these files is used when libuser.conf does not define a value.
# The mapping is documented in the man page.
login_defs = /etc/login.defs
default_useradd = /etc/default/useradd

[defaults]
# The default (/usr/lib*/libuser) is usually correct
# moduledir = /your/custom/directory

# The following variables are usually imported:
# skeleton = /etc/skel
# mailspooldir = /var/mail

crypt_style = md5
modules = files shadow
create_modules = files shadow
# modules = files shadow ldap
# create_modules = ldap

[userdefaults]
LU_USERNAME = %n
# LU_UIDNUMBER = 500
LU_GIDNUMBER = %u
# LU_USERPASSWORD = !!
# LU_GECOS = %n
# LU_HOMEDIRECTORY = /home/%n
# LU_LOGINSHELL = /bin/bash

# LU_SHADOWNAME = %n
# LU_SHADOWPASSWORD = !!
# LU_SHADOWLASTCHANGE = %d
# LU_SHADOWMIN = 0
# LU_SHADOWMAX = 99999
# LU_SHADOWWARNING = 7
# LU_SHADOWINACTIVE = -1
# LU_SHADOWEXPIRE = -1
# LU_SHADOWFLAG = -1

[groupdefaults]
LU_GROUPNAME = %n
# LU_GIDNUMBER = 500
# LU_GROUPPASSWORD = !!
# LU_MEMBERUID =
# LU_ADMINISTRATORUID =

[files]
# This is useful for the case where some master files are used to
# populate a different NSS mechanism which this workstation uses.
# directory = /etc

[shadow]
# This is useful for the case where some master files are used to
# populate a different NSS mechanism which this workstation uses.
# directory = /etc

[ldap]
# Setting these is always necessary.
# server = ldap
# basedn = dc=example,dc=com

# Setting these is rarely necessary, since it's usually correct.
# userBranch = ou=People
# groupBranch = ou=Group

# Set only if your administrative user uses simple bind operations to
# connect to the server.
# binddn = cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com

# Set this only if the default user (as determined by SASL) is incorrect
# for SASL bind operations.  Usually, it's correct, so you'll rarely need
# to set these.
# user = Manager
# authuser = Manager

[sasl]
# Set these only if your sasldb is only used by a particular application, and
# in a particular domain.  The default (all applications, all domains) is
# probably correct for most installations.
# appname = imap
# domain = EXAMPLE.COM
```

Comment: I was not able to show the commented lines, but they are the 'bold' ones.

Answer (score 0):

`system-config-samba` is not installed. Run `sudo apt install system-config-samba`